# Why is the king hoarding magical items?

Tags: magic

I'm running a d&d 5e campaign in which the king has declared the possession of magical items illegal, and any magical item found must immediately be surrendered to the government. In most small towns and villages, average citizens are largely apathetic about the new laws, and usually don't bother to report one another to the authorities for owning seemingly-harmless items with magical properties. The capital city, however, is heavily guarded by the king's sentinels, which detect magic on all who enter/exit the city. So far the players assume that the king has either gone crazy, or he is corrupt, and looking for a specific item or items for some evil reason. I'd prefer the king to stick to a lawful good alignment if possible, even if his goal is extremely misguided.

One idea I've been playing with is that a sentient magic item (crown/scepter/ring/etc) is slowly corrupting the king, and seeking out a specific item for some dastardly purpose. I'm just not sure what it is, or why. I'm relatively new to d&d, so I'm probably unfamiliar with a lot of magical items or properties that would help me come up with better ideas.

Comment: Magic items are dangerous, this is no different than outlawing weapons or outlawing the owning of explosives.

Comment: This looks like a story based question, not a worlbuilding problem.

Comment: Maybe he used to be lawful-good, but just has an epiphany...or maybe he's being influenced by some of the magical toys in the royal bedchamber...or maybe some other Head Of State phoned and asked for a 'favor'. Really, D&D is about imagination. Have fun with it among your friends, since it's not really a good question for this venue.

Answer (score 1):

A magic ritual has been cast in the kingdom. The King's loyal servants disrupted it but did not stop it. The dread beast Cth'aywhl seeks to gain access to the world again. It currently has no anchors in reality due to the failed ritual, but it can use any magic items as small anchors, this is due to a flaw in magic items (or maybe it's intentional?). The King and his advisors are aware of this, but do not wish to cause a panic. They plan on confiscating magic items and placing them in a sacred and warded chamber, which prevents the monster from using them as anchors.

Around unsecured magic items weird effects are slowly occurring, and these are ramping up. The backwaters are soon going to be over run by monstrosities, and the capital a secure bastion. Adventurers who have magic items... might not notice, because they're adventurers and weird stuff always happens near them or in backwater villages.

Answer (score 0):

- Some problem/threat to the kingdom must be held at bay with vast magical force. The court mages found a way to extract "mana" from magic items. The process isn't very efficient at capturing "mana," so they need lots of items to go to the furnaces. All of them, probably.
- There has been a series of "incidents" when amateurs badly mishandled magic items. They affected large numbers of commoners and/or some individuals the king cares about personally. In a knee-jerk reaction, all magic items will be confiscated until a better policy can be established (e.g. examinations and operator permits).

Answer (score 0):

This might be apples to oranges, but you could take inspiration from [King Uther Pendragon](https://merlin.fandom.com/wiki/Uther_Pendragon).

**The king has banned magic because of the grief it has brought him personally, and he wishes none of its evil on his people.** In the BBC series *Merlin*, King Uther makes a deal with a witch to help his infertile wife conceive a heir. He knows full well a life costs a life, but didn't expect this to be paid by his Queen dying in labour. 
The King is enraged and goes after this witch, unsettling the usually peaceful magic community who retaliate, things get out of control and magic is outlawed. In this way, it's an ethical choice on the King's part because the power of magic was turned onto his people for a (very) short time.

In terms of your story, **your King could be attempting to turn the power of magic onto the magic community in revenge or to strike first.** Even in the show, Uther is extraordinarily paranoid that warlocks and witches are plotting his assassination so that magic may reign again (spoiler: this is pretty much the plot thread for half the episodes). His soldiers haven't had much luck crushing magical forces, so maybe it's time to turn to a higher power.

Interestingly the show has a parallel with your campaign, because this outlawing wasn't respected outside of Camelot. No one really had an issue with inter-city mages attacking the inter-city monarchy. They were more worried with their tomato crops and village elders.